# Flutter how to pass arguments to "get" method?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart, they recommend you to use `get` keyword for getters, like:

```
String get text => "Hi there"; // recommended
```

instead of

```
String getText() => "Hi there"; // not recommended
```

I was wondering how can I solve following case using `get`? And if there is no way of doing it then why Dart recommends things like `get`, when things can be done easily by `getX()` way?

```
// how to solve it using recommended way i.e. using "get"?
String getText(bool value) { 
  return value ? "Hi" : "There";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`get` keyword is used for standard getters - when you need just to return some field or value. It's like the such keyword in Kotlin.

But if you want to use some parameters - you can't use `get` in this case - you have to make function `getX([some params])`

Comment: Thank you, that's what I know, I am wondering why Dart team have `get` and `getX()` when `getX()` can do everything a normal `get` does.

Comment: I was a about to give you [this link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-use-getters-for-operations-that-conceptually-access-properties) but it does not answer the essence of your question...

Comment: It's just guidelines and recommendations. If you work with Kotlin - I guess you've faced yellow selection of your code, when studio recommends to use some different code. You can use `getX()` function, but maybe `object.field` will be look more friendly than `object.getField()`. As I've said - it's not strict rule, it's just recommendation

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky I am coming from Java background, so I can't speak for Kotlin, thanks for answering it though.

Comment: You can look here - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html. This is syntax for getters/setters in Kotlin. Maybe it'll help you to understand idea of `get` keyword id Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : you can't do this by using a getter (but your code is valid as you use a method. That's the way to do what you want to achieve).

A getter is meant to access (read or writte) a private property. What you want to achieve does not fit in this description. Therefore, a method is needed.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I know, I am wondering why Dart team have `get` and `getX()` when `getX()` can do everything a normal `get` does, is is more like universal!